# How To Modify Grid Column Width Using Visual State in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml, mytoolkit

For showing results, I am using Data Grid of MyToolKit Package by following below mentioned example: https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid

Using this Grid I am able to show the results. In Order to make grid Responsive I want to set two different Column widths. One is for **Narrow State** and another one is for **Wide State**. 
Here I am adding my grid and visual state code

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding billId}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:PendingBillDetail}" x:Name="colBillId" >
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Name="txtBillId" Text="BillId" Foreground="Green" />
        </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </controls:DataGridTextColumn>
</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

**visual state code**

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="641" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="colBillId.Width" Value="200" />
                <Setter Target="svPendingBillsList.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="narrowView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="colBillId.Width" Value="10" />
                <Setter Target="svPendingBillsList.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Target="svPendingBillsList.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Values are not effecting according to the state.
Please give me your suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: Since your VisualState is auto trigger, you should remove it name (`x:Name="wideView"` and  `x:Name="narrowView"`).

Comment: @Sakura Thanks for your suggestion ... I have tried with your suggestions but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Visual State can't work with your case. In your code, you used  `colBillId.Width` in `VisualState.Setters` to change the column's width. But after your `DataGrid` loaded, there is no control in the Visual Tree named `colBillId`. You can find this in Visual Studio's **Live Visual Tree**:

[image]

For each `DataGridTextColumn`, it's a `ContentPresenter` that contains the `TextBlock` you've set in `DataGridTextColumn.Header`. And as you can see, they are not named. If we want the `Setter` in `VisualState.Setters` to work after the page displayed, we must have the named control in visual tree. As a test, we can use following code in Visual State:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="641" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="colBillId.Width" Value="200" />
                <Setter Target="txtBillId.Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="narrowView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="colBillId.Width" Value="50" />
                <Setter Target="txtBillId.Foreground" Value="Green" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

You will find "BillId" become red if the page's width larger than "641". However the column's width doesn't change. So in your case, Visual State can't work.

As Mirko Bellabarba said, I'd suggest you use Star (*) sizing in `Width` as a workaround. For example:

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding billId}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:PendingBillDetail}">
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Name="txtBillId" Foreground="Green" Text="BillId" />
        </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </controls:DataGridTextColumn>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" Binding="{Binding billId}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:PendingBillDetail}">
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="BillId" />
        </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </controls:DataGridTextColumn>
</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Like written in my answer its possible to acces the columns by index like `MyGrid.Columns[0].Width`.

Comment: @AlexWitkowski: Have you tested your code? As in my test, your code didn't work.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Not now with the DataGrid.. As I wrote in my answer it works for grid so it could/should for the DataGrid - Will give it a try later and have a look on how they implemented the DataGrids Columns.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `x:name` property to the Grid Column you want to change, then use that name in your VisualStateManager
Let me know if it works!

Comment: Have you tried to use width="*" on each column of the DataGrid? Try to set this value directly in the control (not in the VisualStateManager) and set HorizontaAligment="Stretch" for DataGrid, then let me know what happens

Comment: Can you update your answer with all the xaml code? 
Another thing you can try is to manually set the width to some values, e.g: 200px and 500px and see if the UI change accordingly, maybe you have some other problems in the xaml that is not related to DataGrid/VisualStateManager

Comment: @ Mirko Bellabarba Yes When I am giving values manually its applying ... but here my problem is I want to change width of the column.So that I am using Visual State ... But Its not working ... I am using above mentioned code for modifying width... Or else if possible please suggest me with any relevant example

Answer (score 0):

I have a Solution that works for common Grid so it schould also work for your DataGrid.

Give your **DataGrid a name** like:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding billId}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:PendingBillDetail}" x:Name="colBillId" >
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock Name="txtBillId" Text="BillId" Foreground="Green" />
            </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </controls:DataGridTextColumn>
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

And then acces the Column like this in your **visual state code**:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="641" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MyDataGrid.Columns[0].Width" Value="200" />
                <Setter Target="svPendingBillsList.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="narrowView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MyDataGrid.Columns[0].Width" Value="10" />
                <Setter Target="svPendingBillsList.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Target="svPendingBillsList.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

So you have to handle the columns as an indexable. So instead of writing `Target="colBillId.Width"` you should use `Target="MyDataGrid.Columns[0].Width"`

Hope that helps.